# Loop into an empty array with javascript get query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html-framework-7

I want to push the results which I get from mysql into an empty array (totalJuice)

```
var sqlgetgauge = 
"SELECT juice1_num FROM `customers_out` WHERE MONTH(date)=4 ";

   connection.query(sqlgetgauge, function(err, results, field) {
        if (err) throw err;


        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {


            var numberjuice1 = Number(results[i].juice1_num / 100);

            var totalJuice = [];

            totalJuice.push(numberjuice1);
            console.log(totalJuice);

            //This is a Gauge Update
            juice_num_1.update({
                value: numberjuice1,
            });

        }


    });
```

but this code keep showing me result by console.log(totalJuice);

gauge_picker.js:85 [0.5]
gauge_picker.js:85 [0.02]
gauge_picker.js:85 [0.02]

I expect array will be [0.5 ,0.02 , 0.02 ]

and additional question is how I get a total of this array?

Comment: doesn't my solution work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this declaration

```
var totalJuice = [];
```

because it is inside your `for` loop it resets the array each time, meaning you only ever get the last value in the array. You need to move that declaration to before the `for` loop e.g.

```
var totalJuice = [];
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
     ...
```

To get a sum of all the values, after the loop you can do

```
sum = totalJuice.reduce((c, v) => c + v);
```

Comment: Thanks bro ! , but can u explain why sum = totalJuice.reduce((c, v) => c + v); is working? I am still learning

Comment: @FddHongYu there's a good reference for Array reduce and an example of summing an array using `reduce` which shows the longhand and also the ES6 shorthand (which is what my code uses) version of summing an array [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Sum_all_the_values_of_an_array)

Answer (score 2):

As said by @Nick you can declare your array above the for loop and you will get the desired result. And the answer to your second question for calculating the sum of array values you can use array_sum() and pass the array in array_sum function as a parameter.

```
<?php
$a=array(5,15,25);
echo array_sum($a);
?>
```

Hi Hong,

You can see below here how to calculate sum of array values using javascript. You can use reduce method and can pass the function to it this function will get executed for each value of array and will provide you the desired result. Here i had performed addition operation to get sum of array values.

```
var ar = [55,20,30]

    function add(result, num)
    {
       return result + num
    }

    console.log(ar.reduce(add))
```

Comment: @FddHongYu I have edited my post and had provided a way in javascript you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sqlgetgauge = "SELECT juice1_num FROM `customers_out` WHERE MONTH(date)=4";
var totalJuice = [];

connection.query(sqlgetgauge, function(err, results, field) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        var numberjuice1 = Number(results[i].juice1_num / 100);

        totalJuice.push(numberjuice1);

        //This is a Gauge Update
        juice_num_1.update({
            value: numberjuice1,
        });

    }

    const sum = totalJuice.reduce((accumulator, a)=> return accumulator + a );
    console.log(totalJuice);
    console.log("sum of array element",sum)
    console.log("total length",totalJuice.length);
});
```

your console and declaration of array variable was at wrong place and i have printed the total